# Ubuntu 14.04 won-t pass login screen after update and terminal won't accept password

Tags: command-line, login, password

So, I've been using Ubuntu 14.04 for several months now [still a newbie] and today, disaster has struck.

I installed an everyday update, not really sure which, the kinds that I'm prompted for all the time, and upon restarting my computer, it goes to the login screen. This is strange because it never actually had gone to this screen before, just logged straight in. There, I try to login, I put in my password, and it says "login failed". I try to log in as a guest, and "login failed". I try to make any changes or fix things via the crtl alt f1 terminal, and it says that my password is incorrect.

And this isn't a case of forgotten password, I assure you. This seems like the final breaking point of the OS, as it was behaving rather weird lately, like slow and glitchy. Basically, the computer has locked me out and I can't do anything. Clearly I'm going to reinstall the OS in the near future, but really don't want to have to redo the last few days of work since my last backup a few days ago.

I would appreciate any help, and if there's no fix for this, at least a way to grab a copy of my hard drive before blowing this OS away... I'm no expert at this, so please be specific with instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try instructions in the link,
Try to change password from recovery mode and then login using new password...

[Reset Password](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)